# Android Studio Gradle failing during build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Here is my problem scenario:

I am not able to build and run my app within android studio. It seems to fail before installing the apk with the error below. However when I build the app through command line with the gradle wrapper, things go smoothly. Obviously this isn't ideal, as other team members need to use the project, and the IDE UI for android studio should be enough.

When I build and run my app in Android Studio I am getting an error during build steps:

```
transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED 

path may not be null or empty: path='null'
```

However when I invoke command:

```
./gradlew cleanRelease assembleRelease installRelease,
```

This builds and installs the working version on the device.

I can also Build->Generate Signed Apk and this works.

So pressing the Run Button (>) on android studio is the only thing that doesn't work ... Weird thing is it works when I specify only one abi, but when I put all three it doesn't work.

My questions are :

Why is this message showing up ?? What path is null ?? And how to fix this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

////Grab location of opencv sdk
String systemHome = System.getenv('HOME');
File libDir = new File(systemHome + "/Library/Android/sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk");

//If home directory exists choose this path, otherwise we're doing CI 
//with jenkins so we can hardcode this ...
String opencvSdkPath =
    (libDir != null && libDir.isDirectory()) ?
            systemHome + "/Library/Android/sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs"
            :
            "/Users/userx/Library/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs";

println("Look for opencv within " + opencvSdkPath)

android {
signingConfigs {
    XSigningCredentials {
        keyAlias 'asdfsdf'
        keyPassword 'asdfasdf'
        storeFile file('asdfsdf.jks')
        storePassword 'asdfsdf'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
//Give the default configurations for gradles build
defaultConfig {
    //Package name
    applicationId "a.b.c"

    //Minimum working sdk
    minSdkVersion 19

    //Target sdk with support
    targetSdkVersion 25

    //Actual version ID
    versionCode vrsCode as Integer

    //Google play visible version string
    versionName vrsCustomerFacingCode

    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11" ,
                    "-latomic",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_X_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3DS_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD3_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MDL_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD2_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_PLY_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_ASE_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_HMP_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SMD_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MDC_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD5_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_STL_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LWO_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_DXF_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_NFF_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_RAW_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OFF_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_AC_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_BVH_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IRRMESH_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IRR_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_Q3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_B3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COLLADA_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_TERRAGEN_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_CSM_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LWS_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OGRE_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MS3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COB_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_Q3BSP_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_NDO_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IFC_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_XGL_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FBX_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_C4D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OPENGEX_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_ASSBIN_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_BLEND_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GEO_IMPORTER",
                    "-DANDROID -fPIC",
                    "-DANDROID -fsigned-char",
                    "-mstackrealign",
                    "-O2",
                    "-fexceptions",
                    "-frtti"

            cFlags "-latomic",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_X_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3DS_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD3_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MDL_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD2_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_PLY_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_ASE_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_HMP_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SMD_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MDC_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD5_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_STL_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LWO_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_DXF_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_NFF_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_RAW_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OFF_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_AC_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_BVH_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IRRMESH_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IRR_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_Q3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_B3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COLLADA_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_TERRAGEN_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_CSM_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LWS_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OGRE_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MS3D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COB_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_Q3BSP_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_NDO_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IFC_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_XGL_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FBX_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_C4D_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OPENGEX_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_ASSBIN_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_BLEND_IMPORTER",
                    "-DASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GEO_IMPORTER",
                    "-DANDROID -fPIC",
                    "-DANDROID -fsigned-char",
                    "-mstackrealign",
                    "-O2",
                    "-fexceptions",
                    "-frtti"

            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared"

        }
    }
}
splits {

    // Configures screen ABI split settings

    abi {

        // Enable ABI APK splits
        enable true

        // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none
        reset()

        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for
        include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"

        // Specify that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs
        universalApk false
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.XSigningCredentials
        minifyEnabled true
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.properties'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.xml'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs opencvSdkPath, 'src/main/jni/ffmpeg'
    }
    }
}
// map for the version code that gives each ABI a value
ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'x86': 3]

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with an ABI value 
schema
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride =((project.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)) * 1000000)
                    + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'javacpp-presets'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.2'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.0.2-1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.2'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.0.2-1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.2'
compile 'org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.desk:sdk:1.3.1'
compile 'se.akerfeldt:okhttp-signpost:1.1.0'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: this line -> **with jenkins so we can hardcode this ...**  should be commented i guess

Comment: yes.. sorry about that

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here :/ A little explanation will help

Comment: Sure .. I edited the question a bit .. basically I am not able to run the app with android studio .. I've attached my gradle.build file as well as the error ... not sure how to approach this and need help !

Comment: Have you tried setting `minifyEnabled` to false in `buildTypes`-->`release`? Or `useProguard false`

Comment: I can only build release on android studio when obfuscation is off .. so yes I have tried that and it does work but it isn't a solution to the problem

Answer (score 3):

To debug why one of the Gradle tasks fail when pressing the Run button, you can enable command-line options in Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler. Set the Command-line options to --stacktrace --debug. Press the Run button and check the output in the Gradle Console window.

Possibly you have some dependency between the three ABIs that gets reset and affects the others, but it's hard to know without more logs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment.
I would like to know if you are using Instant Run? Don't keep Instant run enabled when trying to build a release apk

Check here for more on [Android studio - Instant run & Proguard](https://publishingfirstandroidapp.blogspot.com/2017/07/android-studio-instant-run-proguard.html)

Comment: Instant run is off .. I find it was being weird when working with split apks